# How to add a number to a variable count in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How do you add a number to a jQuery variable count?

I am trying to compare the COUNT of two variables in jQuery. the first counts the number of checkboxes that are in a field and the other counts how many have been checked. however, for the second count I need to add the number 1 to it.
I will show you what I mean;

```
if($("#product-effect-table input[type=checkbox]").length == $("#product-effect-table input[type=checkbox]:checked"+1).length);
```

you will need note above that I need to add the number 1  to the second part of the equation.

I just tried adding it but I obviously got the syntax wrong and it did not work.

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about

```
  if($("#product-effect-table input[type=checkbox]").length 
           == parseInt($("#product-effect-table input[type=checkbox]:checked").length+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 1 to the length .. not inside a selector..and use `parseInt()`

try this

```
 if($("#product-effect-table input[type=checkbox]").length 
          == 
   parseInt($("#product-effect-table input[type=checkbox]:checked").length + 1))
                                                                         //--^^^here
```

formatted the code so that it is easy to see the changes i made..

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `+1` from where you have it and put it after `.length`:

```
if ( ... $("#product-effect-table input[type=checkbox]:checked").length + 1);
                                                                        ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
if($("#product-effect-table input[type=checkbox]").length == $("#product-effect-table input[type=checkbox]:checked").length + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if($("#product-effect-table input[type=checkbox]").length.toString() == $("#product-effect-table input[type=checkbox]:checked").length.toString()+'1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it on try and tested basis. Get the values for both the count in a variable and debug before doing any comparison.

It's always a good practice to know that you are getting what you desired before implementing any functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple version

```
var chks = $("#product-effect-table input[type=checkbox]");
if(chks.length == chks.filter(":checked").length + 1){
}
```

or

```
if($("#product-effect-table input[type=checkbox]").not(":checked").length == 1){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(parseInt($("#product-effect-table input[type=checkbox]").length) === (parseInt($("#product-effect-table input[type=checkbox]:checked").length)+1);
```